# How could Tom have made "everything go away"?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-invisible-man-2020

In the movie *The Invisible Man* (2020), in the treatment center, Cecilia is visited by Adrian's brother, who claims that he can "make all this go away" if Cecilia agrees to have the baby and goes back to Adrian.

Literally, he says

> Right now, you're a murderer. But I can change that.

Is there any way that he could actually do that? How would he explain the murder of Cecilia's sister? He can't tell the truth of course, but if he doesn't I don't see how there's even a slim chance that anything could explain how Cecilia is holding the very knife that was used to murder her sister a second earlier, with plenty of witnesses around?

Comment: I think he meant to esape her from prison and hide her

Comment: Money can accomplish many things - the easiest one here would probably to make the knife (the only actual proof) disappear - no weapon, no case, she is innocent.

Comment: @TK-421: How could he disappear the knife while everyone in the café saw what happened.

Comment: @C.F.G all the people at the cafe could have been staged or can be bribed not to testify.

Comment: @TK-421: The invisible man is not too fictionious movie. It is just a suit that can be made somehow (but extremely difficult). So it is not easy for who killed Cee sister, to recognize all of that peoples. Of course he can kill everyone who came to testify that is he should wear his suit anyway and this is another option.

Answer (score 2):

Actually if you have an extraordinary power then probably you can change must of things that are independent (less dependent) to "time". One options is that he can wear the invisible suit and go to the judiciary office and change or retype the death or jail sentence. It is nothing for him, because he can enter everywhere he want.

Note that he cannot disappear the knife because everyone in the café saw what happened.